# Выборка данных из массива php

Tags: массивы, php

Приветствую!

Прошу помощи...

Получаю массив данных из API директа в таком виде:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
        [Rest] => 0
        [Status] => some_string
        [IsActive] => No
        [StatusArchive] => No
        [Login] => some_login
        [CampaignID] => 123456789
        [StatusShow] => Yes
        [StartDate] => 2013-12-13
        [Sum] => 0
        [StatusModerate] => New
        [Clicks] => 0
        [Shows] => 0
        [ManagerName] => 
        [StatusActivating] => Pending
        [AgencyName] => 
        [Name] => some_string
    )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
        [Rest] => 0
        [Status] => some_string
        [IsActive] => No
        [StatusArchive] => No
        [Login] => some_login
        [CampaignID] => 123456780
        [StatusShow] => Yes
        [StartDate] => 2013-12-13
        [Sum] => 0
        [StatusModerate] => New
        [Clicks] => 0
        [Shows] => 0
        [ManagerName] => 
        [StatusActivating] => Pending
        [AgencyName] => 
        [Name] => some_string
    )
);
```

Я получаю доступ к данным следующим образом:

```
$result = $api_request->GetCampaignsList(array($api_login));
echo $result[0]->CampaignID;
```

$result[n] где n неизвестное мне количество блоков значений. Вопрос как мне сохранить все $result[n]->CampaignID; в отдельный массив минуя все остальные значения? Помогите составить код корректного цикла.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result = $api_request->GetCampaignsList(array($api_login));
$ids = array();
foreach($result as $item){
   $ids[] = $item->CampaignID;
}
print_r($ids);
```

Comment: И все? Так просто?)) Совсем голово не работает!) Спасибо большое!!!